# long polling vs callback path for asynchronous communication

Tags: java, rest, http, long-polling, polling

What is the best way of communication in the following setup:

- An application platform which registers for some kind of aggregated events at the event processor e.g. three events of type A in one hour
- The event processor which listens to the event producers.

As soon as one of the event pattern occurs the event processor has to notify the platform. I see two major options to achieve this.

Option A:
Long polling seems to be the most common option to achieve this kind of behavior, but it requires to keep a connection open.

Option B:
The other option is to register path with an id e.g. /myplatform/{id} to which the event processor can post to when an event pattern occurred. This would require to keep some mapping of id to event pattern.

Which of these options is preferable in this context.

[image]